# Efficient scheduling jobs with declining profits on multiple machines

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, maximize, np-complete, approximate

**Problem:** Consider the scheduling problem of n jobs on M machines where each job i have a processing time p<sub>i</sub> and gives a profit g<sub>i</sub>(t) if completed by time t. All the jobs are released at time 0. All g<sub>i</sub>(t) are non-increasing functions. For simplicity, we can assume that the machines are not preemptive.

For M=1 and linearly decreasing profit functions. this problem can be solved in O(n) using the greedy algorithm. But for general functions it is NP-complete.

I am interested in the general case. Please give me any link of papers or resource materials for the problem. I searched on the internet but didn't find anything interesting for M>1, though there is previous work on approximating the bounds for M=1.

Please note that I am not expecting you to solve this but just need previous work on the similar problems, if any. And if you have any ideas which can help please feel free to share.

I want know what bounds are know for this problem with m machines and n jobs with same release dates and general non-increasing profit functions. I found a paper towards that direction

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4889v1.pdf

They gave an O(1) approximation when all jobs have identical release times. I want to find similar kind literature for the problem and what ideas they used for solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a "greedy solution" by using a dispatch rule that e.g. minimizes

g<sub>i</sub>(t<sub>0</sub>+p<sub>i</sub>)/p<sub>i</sub>

on the first empty machine (i runs over all not yet scheduled jobs, t<sub>0</sub> is the time, where the first machine is empty).

Then this solution can be improved using Meta-Heuristics like [Simulated Annealing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). A solution can be represented as a tuple of job sequences (one job sequence for each machine). A crucial point is, what "moves" are allowed to change a solution. Maybe for this problem one can find already good solutions with the two basic moves:

- Take one job from one machine and find a new place to insert it.
- Exchange two jobs in the machines' job sequences.

Comment: Can you prove any bound on the solution mentioned above. I mean, Yes your method look promising (and will work in a quite, I guess) but Can there will be no gaurantees on time complexity and how good the final output will be compared to the optimal solution. I am searching more of provable bounds on the problem.

Comment: @cc2 maybe for the given start solution (which is independent of the improvement by Meta Heuristics) a bound can be given, but I cannot tell. For Meta Heuristics one can of course control the runtime, but no bound can be given. It is more a practical thing: carefully designed a Meta Heuristics approach can be very successful in practice.

Comment: This is a good engineering approach, but it was looking for best provable bounds known for the general case of the problem.